# A UDP receiver on android

Tags: android, eclipse, udp

I want to execute a udp receiver on eclipse. But its not working. The udp sender works properly and the packets are sent through the specific port. But emulator is not able to receive any packets through a udp sender. Help needed.

Comment: which device you are using for UDP server and which for UDP client....? did you started UDP server properly before sending packet?

Comment: Show us code so we can examine that please

Answer (score 1):

i don't know what your scenario is but according to my scenario i just setup a UDP server on my system(Windows 7) using php script and successfully sended and received UDP packets from android emulator with the following code.

```
String receivedString="";

        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];

        sendData = stringToBeSended.getBytes();

        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData,
                sendData.length, IPAddress, port);

        DatagramSocket clientSocket;
        try {
            clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();


            clientSocket.send(sendPacket);

            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
                    receiveData.length);
            clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            receivedString = new String(receivePacket.getData());
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            Log.v("SocketExceptionOccured", e.toString())
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v("IOExceptionOccured", e.toString())
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), receivedString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Hello.. :) I'm using the software labview for sending the packets. And want to receive that on emulator. Neways, trying the above code. Hope it works. Tell u later.

Comment: No progress at the receiver side. I didnt get any output on emulator or logcat. I tried simple udp receiver code of receiving packets but no luck. Could anyone please help me in this.